# Facebook Page Application - determine if user is admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Thank you very much for visiting this topic. Currently I'm working on a smaller application that can be installed on facebook pages (not accounts, but separately created pages, like company or fan pages on facebook). I managed to fire up the php SDK for it, even made successful user authentications and played around with access tokens (only user access tokens though).

However my problems arose when I've tried to determine if the current user is an administrator for that facebook page (where the application is installed). 
I've done numerous google searches and research into this topic, but sadly I've realised that most tutorials, questions or related topics are all outdated, or they have obsolete solutions.

I kept running into the 'manage-pages' permission when people advised me to go for page access tokens. However in my opinion asking facebook to grant me manage-pages permission, then prompting users to allow me access to everything on their pages during authentication seems a bit far fetched.

I do not want to modify or read their page contents in any way. I simply want a mini admin page for the application that can be opened by only users that are admins of that certain page. 
I've seen an edit url that can be added in the settings of the application. However I could not find out what it does, or how can I access it if I add an url there. The related documentation on facebook seems to be out of date.

I would be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction with this. Basically I'm looking for a method, that does not require me to use the 'manage_pages' permission, but I can still check out if the current user viewing the installed application on the page is an admin or not. (I wonder if facebook supports an other method for this)

Thank you very much for any kind of tips or aid in this matter!

Comment: You’re talking about Page Tab apps? The info if the currently viewing user is an admin of the page the app is embedded on, can be found in the signed_request that is passed to your app on initial load into the iframe, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#integrating

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @CBroe
Yeah, it's supposed to be a Page Tab app. I'm currently using signed_request with the SDK. Thank you very much for the tip, I'll check it out if it actually passes this information. With your help I've managed to dig up this page, with the variables: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook never gives of fan pages or other pages access.
You have to communicate with facebook page admin and its give a token.
Suppose if you have a permission than it generated token will be you use in your application 
how do you do?

1 communicate with admin.
2 Admin generat token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
3 go to tools and support than it generated token you use in your application.

Note: "Page of admin can it do to generate token"